# Beracha acharona on a mixture of two of the seven species of Israel

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, fruits

If one eats a mixture of two of the 7 species of Israel where one is the ikar and the other a tofel (for example, [Wheaties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheaties) with grapes used as toppings). Using the principal of ikar and tofel, only a mezonot would be required as a beracha rishona (unless things change with the 7 species). If one ate more than a kezayit of each, is a simple al hamichya enough or should one include al haetz?

Comment: @DoubleAA, is oatmeal in the 5 species of grain?

Comment: It's a machloket Rishonim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch O.C. 212:1

> כל שהוא עיקר ועמו טפילה (פירוש דבר בלתי נחשב) מברך על העיקר ופוטר את הטפילה בין מברכה שלפניה **בין מברכה שלאחריה**
>
> Anything which is primary and has a secondary with it, make the blessing on the primary and exempt the secondary, **both in the blessing before and after**.

This applies to a food no matter how "special" it is, as the Shulchan Aruch continues:

> אפילו פת שהוא חשוב מכל אם הוא טפל כגון שאוכל דג מליח ואוכל פת עמו כדי שלא יזיקנו בגרונו מברך על הדג ופוטר את הפת כיון שהוא טפל.
>
> Even bread, which is the most important food, if it is secondary (in a particular dish)... the bread is exempted with the blessing on the other, since it is secondary.

Comment: It's a little different with a mixture of the 7/5 species such that a single beracha can be used with a combination of words ("baruch ata hashem ... al hamichya veal hakolkalah veal haetz veal pri haetz").

Comment: @AniYodeya It's not any different.  It is tafel.  It isn't there as far as the blessing is concerned.  You wouldn't add it if they weren't there.